# Logging into website using Requests Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

**Solution:**  The `action` for this specific site is `action="user/ajax/login"` so this is what has to be appended to url of the main site in order to implement the payload.  (`action` can be found by searching `ctrl + f` for `action` in the `Page Source`).  The `url` is the what is going to be scraped.  The `with requests.Session() as s:` is what is maintaining the cookies from within the site, which is what allows consistent scraping.  The `res` variable is the response that posts the payload into the login url, allowing the user to scrape from a specific account page.  After the post, requests will then attain the specified `url`.  With this in place, BeautifulSoup can now grab and parse the HTML from within the accounts site.  `"html.parser"` and `"lxml"` are both compatible in this case.  If there is HTML from within an `iframe`, it's doubtful it can be grabbed and parsed using only `requests`, so I recommend using `selenium` preferably using Firefox.

```py
import requests

payload = {"username":"?????", "password":"?????"}
url = "https://9anime.to/user/watchlist"
loginurl = "https://9anime.to/user/ajax/login"

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    res = s.get(url)
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
```

[Windows 10] To install Selenium `pip3 install selenium` and for the drivers - (chrome: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)  (Firefox: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)  How to place "geckodriver" into PATH for Firefox Selenium: `control panel` `"environmental variables` `"Path"` `"New"` `"file location for "geckodriver"` `enter` Then your'e all set.
Also, in order to grab the `iframes` when using selenium, try `import time` and `time.sleep(5)` after 'getting' the url with your driver.  This will give the site more time to load those extra `iframes`
Example:

```py
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # The WebDriver for this script
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
time.sleep(5)  # Extra time for the iframe(s) to load
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

print(soup.prettify())  # To see full HTML content
print(soup.find_all("iframe"))  # Finds all iframes

print(soup.find("iframe"))["src"]  # If you need the 'src' from within an iframe.
```

Comment: Try to attach the cookies of a logged-in user? Also it seems quite unlikely that the website would want username and password in clear in a GET request, so maybe you put your credentials in the wrong place.

Comment: The site probably not accepting username and password as a data payload to login via GET.

Comment: @lurker How would I go about finding the required credentials eg: (username, password, crsctoken, etc) for the payload?

Comment: You're misunderstanding my comment. The website probably doesn't accept any credentials via web access with GET unless they have defined a web API. You would have to contact the website owners for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**:  The `action-tag` was `user/ajax/login` in this case.  So by appending that to the original main url of the website - not `https://9anime.to/user/watchlist` but to `https://9anime.to` you get `https://9anime.to/user/ajax/login` and this gives you the login url.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "https://9anime.to/user/watchlist"
loginurl = "https://9anime.to/user/ajax/login"
payload = {"username":"?????", "password":"?????"}
with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    res = s.get(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re trying to make a `GET` request to a URL which requires being logged in to and therefore it is producing a `403` error which means forbidden. This means that the request is not authenticated to view the content.

If you think about it in terms of the URL you're constructing in your `GET` request, you would literally expose the username `(x)` and password `(y)` within the url like so:

`https://9anime.to/user/watchlist?username=x&password=y`

... which would of course be a security risk.

Without knowing what specific access you have to this particular site, in principle, you need to simulate authentication with a `POST` request first and then perform the `GET` request on that page afterwards. A successful response would return a `200` status code `('OK')` and then you would be in a position to use BeautifulSoup to parse the content and target your desired part of that content from between the relevant HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, to start, give the address of the login page and connect. Then you make an

> `input('Enter something')`

to allow you to pause the time you connect (You must hit the ENTER key in the terminal to continue the process once connected and voila.)